# a diferença entre todo, tudo, e todo o?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu estou realmente confundido entre tudo o, tudo, e todo!

Qual é a diferença aqui:

> Nós conhecemos todos os alunos da escola.
>
> Nós conhecemos todos alunos da escola.
>
> Ela mandou tudo pelo correio.
>
> Ela mandou todo pelo correio.
>
> Ela trabalha toda a semana.
>
> Ela trabalha toda semana.

Também existe uma frase como todos?

Por exemplo:

> Este ônibus passa por todas ruas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nos exemplos, os termos **o**, **todo** e **tudo** são, respectivamente, *artigo definido*, *pronome indefinido variável* e *pronome indefinido invariável*.

Uma das funções do artigo definido é indicar o gênero ou o número/quantidade e determinar ou generalizar o substantivo, que — normalmente — vem depois dele. No caso do artigo **a**, ele indica um substantivo feminino no singular, o **o** indica um substantivo masculino no singular. Adicionando o **s** em ambos (**as** e **os**) passamos eles do singular para o plural.

> Ela trabalha toda **a** semana.

Na oração acima, informo que alguém trabalha de domingo a sábado. Ou seja, eu determino os dias através do artigo **a**.

Ademais, o termo **a** determinada qual semana ele trabalhou. Não é uma semana qualquer, é um semana específica.

[image: Dias da semana]

> Ela trabalha toda semana.

Na frase acima, informo que alguém trabalha durante bastantes semanas, mas — diferente daquela oração — eu não determino os dias.

Quando removo o artigo **a** (no contexto apresentado), passo a ideia que alguém trabalha durante várias semanas do mês, mas pode ser que essa pessoa trabalhe uma, duas, três dias por semana.

[image: Dias da semana]

---

Os pronomes indefinidos, por sua vez, referem-se à 3ª pessoa do discurso de forma vaga, imprecisa ou genérica. Porém, diferente do pronome indefinido **toda**, o **todos** possui uma regra de quando usar o artigo.

De acordo com Fernando Pestana, “O artigo é usado depois do pronome indefinido **todos** seguido de substantivo expresso; omitindo-se o substantivo, não se usa o artigo.”

Portanto, tanto faz utilizar:

> Nós conhecemos todos alunos da escola; ou
>   Nós conhecemos todos **os** alunos da escola; ou
>   Nós conhecemos todos **os** *trinta* alunos da escola; ou
>   A professora saiu com todos *trinta* (sem o substantivo, sem o artigo)

Assim como ocorre uma generalização em **toda** e uma inteireza em **toda a**, o mesmo ocorre em **todo/todo os** (generalização) e **todo o** (completude).

Na frase “*Todos* **os** homens merecem uma segunda chance.”, há uma ideia de generalização da espécie em “*Todos* **os** homens”, por isso poderíamos reescrever esse trecho assim: “*Todo* homem merece uma segunda chance.”. Estruturas diferentes, mesmo sentido.

---

É possível usar **todos** na frase abaixo, desde que troque o substantivo feminino *ruas* por um masculino, por exemplo: *lugares*.

> Este ônibus passa por **todas** ruas.
>   Este ônibus passa por **todos** lugares

---

O termo abaixo é o mais usual. *Atenção! O **tudo** é usado para *coisas*.*

> Ela mandou tudo pelo correio.

O **todo**, no contexto abaixo, é necessário que o termo esteja implícito/oculto na oração.

> Ela mandou todo (*o quebra-cabeça*) pelo correio.

[**Fonte**](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6275.md)

Answer (score 1):

> Nós conhecemos todos os alunos da escola.
>
> Nós conhecemos todos alunos da escola.

Estas expressões são sinônimas.

> Ela mandou tudo pelo correio.
>
> Ela mandou todo pelo correio.

Só a primeira expressão é correta e completa. A segunda só faz sentido numa situação anafórica "Onde está o original do livro? - Ele mandou todo pelo correio."

> Ela trabalha toda a semana.
>
> Ela trabalha toda semana.

A primeira expressão tem um sentido unívoco - ela trabalha durante toda a semana, de domingo a domingo. A segunda é ambígua - pode significar que ela trabalha de domingo a domingo (*all the week*), ou que ela trabalha em cada uma das semanas (*all weeks*).